# Regex to match content of HTML body in PHP

Tags: php, regex, multiline, matching

I need a regex in php for matching contents between tags of an element, e.g. `<body>` and `</body>` with the perl compatible `preg_match`.

So far I tried with:

```
// $content is a string with html content

preg_match("/<body(.|\r\n)*\/body>/", $content, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

…but the printout is an empty array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You simply have to add the `s` modifier to have the dot match all characters, including new lines :

```
preg_match("/<body.*\/body>/s", $content, $matches);
```

as explained in the doc : http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 0):

perl regexp match by default one line

you have to specify that you want to do a multi line search by adding a s or a m after the last /

ex:

```
$> perl -e 'print $1 if "bla\nbla\n<body>\nfirst line\n second line\n</body>\nbla" =~ /^.*<body>(.*)<\/body>.*$/s'
```

see:
http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2003/06/06/regexps.html

Comment: Setting the -m flag is not sufficient, as it only changes the behavior of the ^ and $ operators.